# Qt QNetworkAccessManager & multiple QNetworkReplay

Tags: qt, http, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have two http get methods.

First is getting UserID and second is getting full information about current user;

I want to handle finished signlas with different slots

handle GetUserID finished with GetUserIDCompleted and handle GetUserDetails with GetUserDetailsCompleted

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    GetUserID();
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(GetUserIDCompleted(QNetworkReply*)));

    GetUserDetails();
    connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(GetUserDetailsCompleted(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

does it possible to get QNetworkReplay in different SLOTS?

[image]

Comment: Does your GetUserID() and GetUserDetails() are chained network requests? If this is the case then you can build your logic based on  finished() signal of the QNetworkReply instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you can do something like this: having an enum of the different methods

```
enum GetMethod
{
    getUserId,
    getUserDetails
};
```

And you keep a hash of the reply and the corresponding method:

```
QHash<QNetworkReply*, GetMethod> hash;

QNetworkReply *reply1 = nam->post(requestUserId, data);
hash[reply1] = GetMethod::getUserId;

QNetworkReply *reply2 = nam->post(requestUserDetails, data);
hash[reply2] = GetMethod::getUserDetails;

connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

And have one slot that calls the right function

```
void MainWindow::finished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    switch(hash[reply])
    {
    case GetMethod::getUserId:
        GetUserIDCompleted(reply);
        break;
    case GetMethod::getUserDetails:
        GetUserDetailsCompleted(reply);
        break;
    }

    hash.remove(reply);
}
```

I haven't tried it and took some shortcuts but you get the spirit of it =) . It seems that you can retrieve the request with the answer, but I think it is easier with the enum.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

Every operation you do with your QNetworkAccessManager will return a QNetworkReply. This has also has an signal finished. Maybe you can connect this signal to your different slots.

Good luck

Comment: Here's an explanation of how this can be a better approach: http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2011/07/why-qnetworkaccessmanager-should-not-have-the-finishedqnetworkreply-signal/